# how i can skip Please enter your phone (or bot token)?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have several telegram accounts, and at startup, some are asked to enter data. How can I skip this input so that the script continues to run?

my example is not working

```
for f in glob.iglob("*.session"):  # generator, search immediate subdirectories
      print(f.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
      name_file = f.rsplit('.', 1)[0]

      try:
        client = TelegramClient(session=name_file, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

        await send_mes_to_users(client)


      except errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneNumberInvalidError:
         print('fail session')
         continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found a solution. You need to go to your virtual environment, find the Telethon folder, open the client folder, open auth.py, and replace input() with an empty string ''. It won't break anything; it will just skip invalid sessions.

Answer (score -1):

Done

```
try:

client = TelegramClient(session=name_file, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
await client.connect()
if not await client.is_user_authorized():
    print("Error authorisation")
    continue
    await send_mes_to_users(client)
except errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneNumberInvalidError:
    print('fail session')
    continue
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (in v1, both `with` and `start` have the interactive login flow, so by avoiding those you can get rid of the prompt). You can accept your own answer if it solves the original question.